# How to read struct in truffle console?

Tags: contract-development

My struct:

```
struct ContractInfo {
    address contractAddress;
    string name;
    string version;
}
```

Function:

```
function getContractInfo(bytes32 contractHash) public view returns (address contractAddress, string name, string version) {
    ContractInfo storage contractInfo = contracts[contractHash];
    return (contractInfo.contractAddress, contractInfo.name, contractInfo.version);
}
```

When I try to run function in truffle console I get this result:

> truffle(test)> ContractRegistry.deployed().then(function(i){cr = i})
>
> truffle(test)> cr.getContractInfo("a66258df673fb6a40d8868da50898ad3db8ba197dcfcd3b370bde7cb93c7d500")
>
> [ '0x6433623337306264653763623933633764353030', '', '' ]

Remix shows correct:

> 0: address: contractAddress 0x1Aab044DB8d37979d3180B40F2171E8bd4a8eca9
>
> 1: string: name ContractToBeStored
>
> 2: string: version 1.0

How can I read multiple values in console?

Answer (score 0):

I was storing and retrieving by wrong byte32:
instead of a66258df673fb6a40d8868da50898ad3db8ba197dcfcd3b370bde7cb93c7d500 should be **0x**a66258df673fb6a40d8868da50898ad3db8ba197dcfcd3b370bde7cb93c7d500.